# Integration test not able to mock for methods annotated with @CircuitBreaker

Tags: java

Integration test not able to mock RestTemplate field on methods annotated with @CircuitBreaker.

controller:

```
@RestController
public class CollegeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CollegeService collegeService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/college/student/{collegeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> getCollegeStudent(@PathVariable String collegeId){
        
        ResponseEntity<Map> studentByCollege = collegeService.getStudentByCollege(collegeId);
        
        return studentByCollege;
    }
}


Service:
```

@Service
public class CollegeServiceImpl implements CollegeService {

```
public static final String COLLEGE_SERVICE = "collegeService";

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

int count = 0;

@Override
@Retry(name = COLLEGE_SERVICE/*, fallbackMethod = "fallbackForRetry"*/)
@CircuitBreaker(name = COLLEGE_SERVICE, fallbackMethod = "getAllStudentFallback")
public ResponseEntity<Map> getStudentByCollege(String collegeId) {

    ResponseEntity<Map> forEntity = null;
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/student/{collegeId}";
    System.out.println(" count = " + ++count);
    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
    forEntity =  restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,request, Map.class,collegeId);
     
    
    //return testCircuitBreakerInFunctionalProgramming().apply(collegeId);
    //throw new RuntimeException("abc");
    return forEntity;
}

public ResponseEntity<Map> getAllStudentFallback(String collegeId, Throwable t) {

    System.out.println("fallback method");
    return null;
}

public ResponseEntity<Map> getAllStudentFallback(String collegeId, CallNotPermittedException t) {

    System.out.println("fallback call not permitted method");
    return null;
}
```

Integration Test :

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class CollegeIntegrationTest {
    
    //@InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private CollegeController controller;
    
    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private CollegeServiceImpl service;
    
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        
    }
    
    
    @Test
    public void testCollege() {
        ResponseEntity<Map> response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.same(HttpMethod.GET),Mockito.<HttpEntity> any(), Mockito.any(Class.class),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);
        controller.getCollegeStudent("102");
        
    }

}
```

What I am doing:
1 of the micorservice is down and I am implementing CircuitBreaker for that scenario and Its working as expected.

Issue:
When I am not using CircuitBreaker annotation, mock of RestTemplate is available with same id in service class. i.e Mocking working fine as expected.

In case when I use @CircuitBreaker, some mock id is generated in IntegrationTest class but the same is not available on service, so not able to mock restcall.

I am initializing rest template using :

```
 @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        
         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         return restTemplate;
    }
```

In whole mocking is not working as expected while using @CircuitBreaker.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.